# Kendo .cshtml column enable value true or false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Code blocks which are mentioned below.

```
<div class="form-group">
<span>Sipariş No</span>
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(x => x.OrderNo).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

I want this column based on condition enable value false or enable value true.
condition mean other column value true or false

other column snippet is mentioned below.

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:20px">
@(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(x => x.integration).Label("Entegrasyon"))</div>
```

How can doing this case?

Comment: So selecting the checkbox should enable the textbox, and clearing the checkbox should disable the textbox, and you want to know how to achieve this--is that correct?  If so, you can use JavaScript to handle the checkbox change event (see https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/checkbox/events/change).  If it does not work, please elaborate on which part of the code is failing.

Comment: Firstly I open  new save pop screen. new save screen into  integration checkbox and OrderNo textbox. If I select checkbox true and if save after than same record for the update open I want order no column enable value(false) but if I select false checkbox and save. This time order no colum enable value(true)

Comment: I believe the question as written is too broad and ambiguous to effectively answer. To increase your chances of getting an answer, you may want to read the following and update the question to make it more specific: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask